# Google sheets APIv4: Getting notes from cell

Tags: google-sheets-api

I can't find a way to retrieve notes from a cell. I looked here:https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get

I can update the note by using the code here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells

... but I can't find a way to retrieve the note in the first place.

This the result of a `values.get` call on a cell that has a note...

`{u'range': u'Sheet1!D5', u'values': [[u'update CD data']], u'majorDimension': u'ROWS'}`

as you can see, the notes to the cell are not there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `sheets/data/rowData/values/note` to the fields?

The endpoint is as follows.

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### Spreadsheet ID ###?fields=sheets%2Fdata%2FrowData%2Fvalues%2Fnote
```

From your profile, if you use Python, how about this?

```
response = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=id, fields="sheets/data/rowData/values/note").execute()
```

#### Result:

When there are notes at "A1:B2", the result is as follows.

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "note": "sample note A1"
                },
                {
                  "note": "sample note B1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "note": "sample note A2"
                },
                {
                  "note": "sample note B2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Reference:

- [CellData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike! Is there a way to determine which worksheet and what range to retreive information from instead of getting all notes from all sheets in a given spreadsheet? My goal is to import all cell values from a specific sheet along with their notes (I need pairs of cell value + cell note), that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Karolina Andruszkiewicz At first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About your question, unfortunately, I cannot understand it. But I would like to support you. So in order to correctly understand about your question, can you post it as new question by including more information? For example, can you include the sample input and output you expect in your question? By this, I would like to try to understand about your question. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?